# "The human whose name is written in this note shall die" Is this correct English?

Tags: word-choice

The English sentence in the title is the quote from the famous Japanese Manga, Death note. Although I am a non-native speaker of English, the English sounds somehow wrong to me. Should "the note" in the sentence be "the notebook"?
How does it sound to you guys?

Answer (score 2):

It's correct. "note" refers to a short informal letter whether written or spoken exactly like "message".